# What's the probability that Tom's bag will weigh more than Sally's?

Tags: probability, algorithms

Assume all cantelopes take on an integer weight in ounces from 0 (an extremely light apple) to 1000 inclusive.

Tom has 50 cantelopes of weights $\{T_i: 1\leq i\leq 50\}$. Sally also has 50 cantelopes, of weights $\{S_i\}$ (note that Sally's weight-set is potentially different from Tom's).

Each of them randomly selects 20 of their cantelopes and puts them in a (weightless) bag. I am trying to compute the probability that Tom's bag of cantelopes weighs more than Sally's bag in terms of the 50 $T_i$s and 50 $S_i$s.

One thing we can do is compute all possible combinations of size 20 for each of Tom and Sally's cantelopes. Then, for each of Sally's combinations, we can iterate through the combinations of Tom's cantelopes and find out how many weigh less.

However, this takes too long to compute. Is there a faster way?

Comment: To be clear: selection here is without replacement, correct?

Comment: The $50$ does not seem relevant.

Comment: Yeah, selection is without replacement. 50's relevant since I'm given the 50 weights for each person.

Comment: So the $S_i$, $T_i$ are numbers, not random variables?

Comment: Yeah, they're numbers.

Comment: What is the prior distribution of cantelopes? Discrete uniform on $\{1,\ldots,1000\}$? Are Tom and Sally picking their 50 cantelopes randomly? What do you mean by "probability that Tom's bag of cantelopes weighs more than Sally's bag in terms of the 50 Tis and 50 Sis."?

Comment: If you can find the individual generating functions for Tom and Sally then it's not too hard to find the probability that one is greater than the other.  Unfortunately, finding those individual generating functions looks like a Hard Problem - if it were with replacement then you could just take the $20^{\mathrm{th}}$ power of the generating function $\sum_i x^{S_i}$, but I don't believe there's a clean way of getting those generating functions; there may be some inclusion-exclusion based approach, though...

Comment: (I'm presuming, incidentally, that the initial 'picking step' is a red herring - rather, we're given sets $\{S_i\}$ and $\{T_i\}$ of 50 (natural) numbers each that simply _are_ the weights of the canteloupes, and then sets of 20 are chosen randomly, one from each set of 50.  If this is so, then I would recommend editing the question to say as much, because the current form is obviously a bit confusing.)

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant. K.